# Why doesn't the Set contain the Point

Tags: dart

I have a `Set<Point<double>>` and I want to test if the set contains a particular `Point<double>`.

My understanding is that if two `Point<double>` instances have the same `hashCode` and are equal according to `==`, then the default `Set` implementation considers them identical and will return `true` when one of the points is in the set and we test for the other using `contains`.

But in the following example this doesn't seem to be the case:

```dart
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  final points = Set<Point<double>>.identity();
  final a = Point<double>(5, 2);
  final b = Point<double>(5, 2);

  points.add(a);

  print("a == b ? ${a == b}");
  print("a.hashCode == b.hashCode ? ${a.hashCode == b.hashCode}");
  print("points.contains(a) ? ${points.contains(a)}");
  print("points.contains(b) ? ${points.contains(b)}");  
}
```

[According to DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/65d9cdac5c57865348138cdf8a5cb4e0) the output is:

```
a == b ? true
a.hashCode == b.hashCode ? true
points.contains(a) ? true
points.contains(b) ? false
```

Where have I gone wrong here?

Comment: I notice that if I make the two points `const` rather than `final`, `points.contains(b)` succeeds. It also succeeds if I add `a` to the set by initialising the set with `a` by using `final points = Set<Point<double>>.from([a])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because thay are not identical but you specified to compare them by identity instead of equilvalence.

```
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  //final points = Set<Point<double>>.identity();
  final points = Set<Point<double>>();
  final a = Point<double>(5, 2);
  final b = Point<double>(5, 2);

  points.add(a);

  print("a == b ? ${a == b}");
  print("a.hashCode == b.hashCode ? ${a.hashCode == b.hashCode}");
  print("points.contains(a) ? ${points.contains(a)}");
  print("points.contains(b) ? ${points.contains(b)}");
}
```

You disabled this operator.

```
 /**
   * A `Point` is only equal to another `Point` with the same coordinates.
   *
   * This point is equal to `other` if, and only if,
   * `other` is a `Point` with
   * [x] equal to `other.x` and [y] equal to `other.y`.
   */
  bool operator ==(dynamic other) =>
      // Cannot change parameter type to `Object` in case some class
      // inherits the type and uses their argument dynamically.
      other is Point && x == other.x && y == other.y;
```

This is explains this in details (use equals: identical).

```
/**
   * Creates an insertion-ordered identity-based set.
   *
   * Effectively a shorthand for:
   *
   *     new LinkedHashSet<E>(equals: identical,
   *                          hashCode: identityHashCode)
   */
  external factory LinkedHashSet.identity();
```

Comment: Good grief... I was explicitly using the `identity` constructor. Here I was thinking that  `Set.identity()` meant something along the lines of a mathematical identity or even an identity matrix, woops, should have double checked the docs. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`Set<Point<double>>.identity()` uses idenity hash for comparing. But `Point` has overriden comparsion by equality of x and y [(See source code)](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/ddc-2.1.0-dev.7.1/sdk/lib/math/point.dart#L26)

So in this case `a.idenityHash != a.hashcode` and `a.idenityHash != b.idenityHash` even if `a.hashCode == b.hashCode`. This all happend because `==` and `hashCode` were overriden for object compararsion by coordinates.

So if you create normal set, which is using hashCode methods for comparsion, you get expected result

```
final points = Set<Point<double>>();
points.add(a);
print("points.contains(b) ? ${points.contains(b)}"); // true
```

Comment: Thank you, for the clear explanation! I hadn't realised that's what the Set's `identity` constructor meant. And by setting the instances to `const` they had the same identity too.